# How do I re-render a component when an object is changed in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple expense log app in React and would like to display the latest data every time the `expensesLog` object is updated. On clicking the button, the `clickHandler` function is called and the object is updated but nothing seems to change on the UI inspite of me mapping the `expenseLog` object. Here's my code :

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  var expenseLog = [
    {
      name: "Expense1",
      amount: 1000
    },
    {
      name: "Expense2",
      amount: 100
    }
  ];

  var [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  var [name, setName] = useState("");

  const inputChangeHandler = (e) => { 
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

  const inputChangeHandler2 = (e) => { 
    setCount(e.target.value);
  }
  
  const clickHandler = () => { 
    expenseLog = [...expenseLog, {name: name, amount: count}];
    document.querySelector('.inputField').value = "";
    document.querySelector('.inputField2').value = 0;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={inputChangeHandler} className='inputField'/>
      <input type={"number"} onChange={inputChangeHandler2} className='inputField2'/>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}></button>
      {expenseLog.map(expense => <p>{expense.name} {expense.amount}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you not put your expenses in a useState?

Comment: You shouldn't be using native DOM methods like `querySelector` with React. React has its own specific way of updating that DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `expenseLog` is defined in the function body of your react component. That means react will initialize the variable on every render and thus forget all state that you mutated.

As you did with `count` and `name`, you need to wrap `expensesLog` into a React `useState` hook in order to maintain state inside your component.

Answer (score 2):

It's not updating UI as expenseLog is just object, and it's immutable when you don't change the reference.

So, you need to use expenseLog as State variable. And update it inside callback function using setExpenseLog for updating the state.

```js
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [expenseLog, setExpenseLog] = useState([
    {
      name: "Expense1",
      amount: 1000,
    },
    {
      name: "Expense2",
      amount: 100,
    },
  ];)

  var [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  var [name, setName] = useState("");

  const inputChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const inputChangeHandler2 = (e) => {
    setCount(e.target.value);
  };

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setExpenseLog(prev => [...prev,{ name: name, amount: count } ])
    
    document.querySelector(".inputField").value = "";
    document.querySelector(".inputField2").value = 0;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={inputChangeHandler} className="inputField" />
      <input
        type={"number"}
        onChange={inputChangeHandler2}
        className="inputField2"
      />
      <button onClick={clickHandler}></button>
      {expenseLog.map((expense) => (
        <p>
          {expense.name} {expense.amount}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the data to a new `expenses` state.
2. Remove the `count` and `name` states, and add a new one `input` that deals with both input changes.
3. Add a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to each input. We can use that to update the `input` state when it changes.
4. Remove the native DOM methods. When you click the button reinitialise the input state. The change in state will be reflected in the input values.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {

  const inputInit = { name: '', amount: 0 };

  const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState(data);
  const [input, setInput] = useState(inputInit);

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { dataset: { type }, value } = e.target;
    setInput({ ...input, [type]: value });
  }
  
  function handleClick() { 
    const { name, amount } = input;
    setExpenses([ ...expenses, { name, amount } ]);
    setInput(inputInit);
  }

  return (
    <div onChange={handleChange}>
      Name: <input data-type="name" type="text" value={input.text}/>
      Amount: <input data-type="amount" type="number" value={input.number} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add entry</button>
      <div className="list">
        {expenses.map(obj => {
          return <p>{obj.name}: {obj.amount}</p>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}

const data=[{name:'Expense1',amount:13},{name:'Expense2',amount:100}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
* { font-size: 0.95em; }
input { display: block; }
button { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```